# .htaccess Rewrite without index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a URL with the structure `http://localhost/slugone/dynamicslug?query=00000`, which I am trying to rewrite to `http://localhost/slugone/dynamicslug/00000`.

I've managed to get .htaccess to recognise this `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteRule ^slugone/(.*)/(.*)$ /slugone/$1?query=$2 [L,R=301]
```

But this doesn't do what I need it to, instead of masking `/slugone/dynamicslug/00000` to be `/slugone/dynamicslug?query=00000`, it is instead redirecting the pretty URL to the URL with query parameters.

`/dynamicslug/` is a slug that is used to show a specific product on the page, and the `?query=00000` is used to select a variant of this product, so I can't explicitly use `/dynamicslug/` in my rewrite rule, either.

Searching SO hasn't given me any results, as all of the questions I can find are using `index.php` in their rewrite, which I am not.

Comment: First, why not just remove `index.php` from those other rules? There's nothing magic about it; it's just text. Second, are you sure you really want a redirect here? That's the opposite of what people typically want in these situations. It seems much more likely that what you want is to enable use of the "pretty" URL (the one without parameters) to access the URL with parameters, without doing a redirect.

Comment: Hi Ed, Sorry, I've not been clear there. I've updated the question, I am after a pretty URL, and not a redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reverse your RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^query=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^slugone/([^/]+)$ /slugone/$1/%1? [L,R=301]
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you want it to behave as a pretty URL you should only remove the redirection in your initial RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^slugone/(.*)/(.*)$ /slugone/$1?query=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Hi Florian, Sorry, I've not been clear. I'm not after a redirect and am after a pretty URL. Secondly, I can't use `slugtwo` in the rule, as its a dynamic slug from the CMS I am using. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Then you should juste remove the Redirection part of your initial RewriteRule. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks Florian, this definitely sent me down the right path.